# How to replace the default `geom_ribbon` with `geom_errorbar` in `ggcompetingrisks` from `survminer` package?

Tags: r, survminer, geom-ribbon

How to replace the default `geom_ribbon` with `geom_errorbar` in `ggcompetingrisks` from `survminer` package?

`conf.int = T` will put confidence interval as a ribbon layer.

my code:

```
library(cmprsk);library(survminer)
  set.seed(2)
  ss <- rexp(100)
  gg <- factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),1:3,c('BRCA','LUNG','OV'))
  cc <- factor(sample(0:2,100,replace=TRUE),0:2,c('no event', 'death', 'progression'))
  strt <- sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)
  
  # handles cuminc objects
  print(fit <- cmprsk::cuminc(ss,cc,gg,strt))
  ggcompetingrisks(fit, multiple_panels = FALSE, conf.int = TRUE)
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the source code of the two required functions from the survminer package (`ggcompetingrisks.cuminc()` & `ggcompetingrisks()`), e.g.

```r
#install.packages("cmprsk")
library(cmprsk)
#> Loading required package: survival
library(survminer)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggpubr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'survminer'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:survival':
#> 
#>     myeloma

set.seed(2)
ss <- rexp(100)
gg <- factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),1:3,c('BRCA','LUNG','OV'))
cc <- factor(sample(0:2,100,replace=TRUE),0:2,c('no event', 'death', 'progression'))
strt <- sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)

# handles cuminc objects
print(fit <- cmprsk::cuminc(ss,cc,gg,strt))
#> Tests:
#>                    stat        pv df
#> no event    0.008709109 0.9956549  2
#> death       1.629098402 0.4428389  2
#> progression 2.605007849 0.2718502  2
#> Estimates and Variances:
#> $est
#>                           1         2         3         4
#> BRCA no event    0.17241379 0.2758621 0.2758621 0.2758621
#> LUNG no event    0.25641026 0.3076923 0.3076923 0.3333333
#> OV no event      0.15625000 0.2500000 0.3125000 0.3125000
#> BRCA death       0.24137931 0.2758621 0.2758621 0.2758621
#> LUNG death       0.07692308 0.2307692 0.2307692 0.2307692
#> OV death         0.21875000 0.3437500 0.3750000 0.3750000
#> BRCA progression 0.34482759 0.4137931 0.4137931 0.4137931
#> LUNG progression 0.25641026 0.3589744 0.3846154 0.3846154
#> OV progression   0.18750000 0.2812500 0.2812500 0.2812500
#> 
#> $var
#>                            1           2           3           4
#> BRCA no event    0.005277565 0.007933520 0.007933520 0.007933520
#> LUNG no event    0.005083701 0.005740953 0.005740953 0.006209164
#> OV no event      0.004338366 0.006323011 0.007854783 0.007854783
#> BRCA death       0.006783761 0.007478906 0.007478906 0.007478906
#> LUNG death       0.001887310 0.004961788 0.004961788 0.004961788
#> OV death         0.005593145 0.007641923 0.008089627 0.008089627
#> BRCA progression 0.008299977 0.009699862 0.009699862 0.009699862
#> LUNG progression 0.005097395 0.006324651 0.006608777 0.006608777
#> OV progression   0.004972034 0.006833076 0.006833076 0.006833076
ggcompetingrisks(fit, multiple_panels = FALSE, conf.int = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
ggcompetingrisks_cuminc_altered <- function(fit, gnames = NULL, gsep = " ", multiple_panels = TRUE, 
          coef = 1.96, conf.int = FALSE) 
{
  if (!is.null(fit$Tests)) 
    fit <- fit[names(fit) != "Tests"]
  fit2 <- lapply(fit, `[`, 1:3)
  if (is.null(gnames)) 
    gnames <- names(fit2)
  fit2_list <- lapply(seq_along(gnames), function(ind) {
    df <- as.data.frame(fit2[[ind]])
    df$name <- gnames[ind]
    df
  })
  time <- est <- event <- group <- NULL
  df <- do.call(rbind, fit2_list)
  df$event <- sapply(strsplit(df$name, split = gsep), `[`, 
                     2)
  df$group <- sapply(strsplit(df$name, split = gsep), `[`, 
                     1)
  df$std <- std <- sqrt(df$var)
  pl <- ggplot(df, aes(time, est, color = event))
  if (multiple_panels) {
    pl <- ggplot(df, aes(time, est, color = event)) + facet_wrap(~group)
  }
  else {
    pl <- ggplot(df, aes(time, est, color = event, linetype = group))
  }
  if (conf.int) {
    pl <- pl + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = est - coef * std, 
                               ymax = est + coef * std), alpha = 0.2)
  }
  pl + geom_line()
}

ggcompetingrisks_altered <- function (fit, gnames = NULL, gsep = " ", multiple_panels = TRUE, 
          ggtheme = theme_survminer(), coef = 1.96, conf.int = FALSE, 
          ...) 
{
  stopifnot(any(class(fit) %in% c("cuminc", "survfitms")))
  if (any(class(fit) == "cuminc")) {
    pl <- ggcompetingrisks_cuminc_altered(fit = fit, gnames = gnames, 
                                  gsep = gsep, multiple_panels = multiple_panels, 
                                  coef = coef, conf.int = conf.int)
  }
  if (any(class(fit) == "survfitms")) {
    pl <- ggcompetingrisks.survfitms(fit = fit)
  }
  pl <- pl + ggtheme + ylab("Probability of an event") + xlab("Time") + 
    ggtitle("Cumulative incidence functions")
  ggpubr::ggpar(pl, ...)
}


ggcompetingrisks_altered(fit, multiple_panels = FALSE, conf.int = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Is that the outcome you're after?

Comment: @Jared doubt so how you can read inside the function plus make the edit to the function then run Im a very basic R user But i would like to know how to do this so that i can learn what is inside the function and if I have to try or modify how to do it

Comment: Source code is [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/survminer/src/R/ggcompetingrisks.R). From within Rstudio there is a shortcut to view the source of a loaded function: the `F2` key (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-the-RStudio-IDE). For the solution above I copied the source code and made the changes you requested (switched `geom_ribbon()` for `geom_errorbar()`) and named the function a different name ("ggcompetingrisks_altered" instead of "ggcompetingrisks"). This type of manipulation is rarely needed in R, so I wouldn't worry too much about learning it